# "Like Button" does not appear when I paste plug-in code into HTML snippet on iweb?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Please help. I've spent hours on this. With Twitter I had no trouble adding a button to my website using iWeb but with facebook..... 
The best way I can describe my problem is this: I go through all of the required steps to obtain the plug-in for my facebook page (http://www.facebook.com/thekitchensinkwma). I then "get code", copy the code, drag HTML Snippet onto my desired page in iWeb, then paste the code into the appropriate window (BTW: I've tried all 3 codes several times). When Click the "Apply" button, the "Like" button does not appear. 
I'm at my whit's end! Please help. Thanks.
Martin

Comment: give us a link so we can have a looksie

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the page I have two initial thoughts you can run down:

1. Your CMS [iWeb or whatever you are using] is altering the fb-root  tag which is required for the button to show. Twitter only uses javascript.
2. Your page is appearing via iframe, javascript or something from the system is causing Facebook to believe you may be hiding the button to fake a click.

If this is happening with both the iFrame and Scripted method a url will be helpful as it may be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">` to the HTML-tag.

Would be easier if you provided a link though.